# A "using" statement gets moved automatically outside of the namespace

Tags: c#, templates, using-statement

A file within a custom VS project template is getting altered automatically by VS when the template is used to create a project.

Code in the template zip file:

```
using Enterprise.Utilities.ServiceBase.Requests;
using Enterprise.Utilities.ServiceBase.Responses;

namespace TemplateAspnetCore.ExamplesRestService
{
    using System = global::System;
    // ....
}
```

Code when the template is used to create a new project:

```
using Enterprise.Utilities.ServiceBase.Requests;
using Enterprise.Utilities.ServiceBase.Responses;
using System = global::System;

namespace NewProjectName.ExamplesRestService
{
    // ....
}
```

Any ideas on what might cause a using statement to move outside the namespace?

I expected the file to remain as is, and expected the using statement to stay within the namespace, as in the original file.

I can fix the issue in the created project by moving that using statement back into the namespace. But since it's a template, it would be nice if no manual step were required.

Comment: Try playing with [`csharp_using_directive_placement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0065) and/or `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0065`.